# How find the probability that the sum of random variables smaller than a value?

Tags: calculus, probability

A lamp uses one bulb with an average lifespan of 1100 hours. We bought two bulbs, so once the first bulb burns out, we replace it with a second of the same type. Assuming we can model the probability of failure of these bulbs by an exponential density function with mean $\mu=1100$, how to find the probability that we can keep the lamp lit longer than 1700 hours?
 I got something like **0.457**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDORX.png)

Comment: Hint: this site supports Latex and also you could learn it. I completely rewrote your title on obvious reasons. If you ask a question, *choose the title very carefully, it is so important as your whole question body!*

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the lifespan of two lamps is the sum of two exponential variables with mean 1100. It will be a Gamma distribution.

Check out sum of exponential variables, there are several posts on it on this site, for example.

Comment: I found a lot of resources on this site but my answer always go wrong that why I decide to ask

Comment: @BenDang Then insert your tries into the question, it significantly improves the probability that it won't be moderated out. Nobody likes people just putting their homework here. Be a hunter. Hunt for the solution of a problem. That we like.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $X_{1},X_{2} \sim Exp(\mu)$ with $\mu = 1100$

The pdf of the exponential density is given by

$$f(x;\lambda ) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} &  \textrm{ for  }  x \geq 0 \\ \\ 0  &  \textrm{ for  } x < 0 \end{cases} \end{align}$$

then the sum $ X= X_{1} +X_{2}$ is given by

$$ f_{X}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_{1}}(x-x_{2})f_{X_{2}}(x_{2}) dx_{2} $$

$$ f_{X}(x) = \int_{0}^{x}  \lambda e^{- \lambda (x-x_{2})}\lambda e^{-\lambda x_{2} }  dx_{2}$$
$$ f_{X}(x) = \int_{0}^{x}  \lambda^{2} e^{-\lambda x}  dx_{2}$$

$$ \lambda^{2} x e^{-\lambda x}$$

$$f_{X}(x) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} \lambda^{2} x e^{-\lambda x} &  \textrm{ for  }  x \geq 0 \\ \\ 0  &  \textrm{ for  } x < 0 \end{cases} \end{align}$$

The gamma distribution density function is

$$ f(x,\alpha, \beta)  = \frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}$$

then $X=X_{1} +X_{2} \sim Gamma(\alpha,\beta) $ where$ \alpha =2,\beta =1110$

Now $X \sim Gamma(2,1100)$

Then the pdf is given by

$$ f(x,2,1100) = \frac{1100^{2}}{\Gamma(2)}x e^{-1100 x}$$

Ok,  now the probability of keeping the lamp lit longer than $1700$ hours then

Now the cumulative distribution function for the gamma density is given by

$$F(x,\alpha, \beta) = \int_{0}^{x} f(u,\alpha, \beta) du = \frac{\gamma( \alpha, \beta x)}{\Gamma(\alpha) } $$

$$ \int_{0}^{1700} 1100^{2}x e^{- 1100 x} dx $$
$$1100^{2} \int_{0}^{1700} xe^{-1100x} dx \approx 1 $$

There is approximately 100% chance it is under 1700 hours. Now using your method.

Note this method ignores the gamma method. All we did it find the joint pmf and then find the cdf.

Comment: my instructor did not teach us about gamma distribution so it hard to understand your explanation. I'm learning about Probability Using the Exponential Density Function

Comment: Ok..but now you have the sum of exponential densities. You can find the expectation and variance. The fact it looks like a gamma distribution is just a side note.

Comment: @BenDang put your image in the question header with latex